# How to map Json type value in mongodb with Morphia

Tags: mongodb, scala, morphia

As below, how to write the mapping for liknurl which is also a json type value in Play Framework?

```
@Entity(value = "appstore", noClassnameStored = true)
class Ad {
  @Id
  var id = new ObjectId()
  var name = ""
  var linkurl = ""
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("52d4d85e4dd5f5a2e81921ab"),
  "name":"test"
  "linkurl" : {
   "pc" : "http://www.example.com",
   "android" : "http://example.com/android",
   "ios" : "http://example.com/ios"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just define the json type value as String and use play.api.libs.json._ to get the value as shown below

```
  val pclink = Json.stringify(Json.parse(Ad.linkurl) \ "pc"
```